# Why does Python ThreadPoolExecutor.map takes so long to start yielding results, compared to ProcessPpplExecutor?

Tags: python, generator, python-multithreading

Take this example program:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor

def fun(xx):
    for _ in range(10):
        y = 1
        x = xx
        while x > 0:
            y = (y * x) % 1000000007
            x -= 1
    print("END {}! = {}".format(xx, y))
    return xx, y

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
    out = executor.map(fun, range(10000))
    for x in out:
        print(x)
```

This lets me see messages printed each time the function is actually calculated, and also from when the outputs are read in the output generator. One should expect function messages not to be strictly in order ,while the generator is. Also, I expect the generator to provide me data "as a pipeline", giving me intermediate results before the whole input is processed. This could be potentially an infinite stream that I am processing.

If I use `ProcessPoolExecutor`, this works just like I expected, and I soon can start reading from the output generator while new results are being created by the thread pool. With `ThreadPoolExecutor`, on the other hand, while it seems it works fine, it only starts providing me with output after a lot of function executions have already happened. For instance:

```
END 6363! = 280520285
END 6364! = 231081245
END 6365! = 832114135
END 6366! = 238546331
(0, 1)
(1, 1)
(2, 2)
(3, 6)
(4, 24)
END 6368! = 281286418
END 6369! = 513183705
END 6370! = 980177974
```

Why is there such a huge difference, and how can I control this behavior? If I want to use threads, and I want to make sure I have results faster, should I just chunk the data myself instead of relying on `map`?

Answer (score 0):

one reason you get result faster in ProcessPoolExecutor is that it makes chunks of iterator , so each chunk arsines to a core of cpu(number of worker you assigned) and that core might finish calculation of its chunk faster and it could go further and execute your for loop